# Contructor method isnt setting an attribute in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, constructor, interface

I am using typescript and typeorm;

Here i created a repository class that uses the methods from typeorm, and then i use a constructor inside my Controller class to get this repository as an attribute, but for some reason it doesnt recognizes this.teamRepo in my other method, althoug when i console.log(this.teamRepo) inside my constructor or call repo methods inside the cosntructor it works, and when i create a const outside my class or inside the method it worked fine aswell;

The first piece code is the way i am trying to make work, calling the teamRepo as an attribute from my controller class, the second piece of code is an example of how i got it running and i dont know it worked in one way but not in the other:

Any helps is welcome :)

```
class TeamController {

    private teamRepo: TeamRepository;

    constructor() {
        const repo = new TypeOrmTeamRepo(); 
        this.teamRepo = new TeamRepository(repo);
        // console.log(this.teamRepo) ==> recieve corret
    }

    public async addTeam(request: Request, response: Response) {
        try {
            // console.log(this.teamRepo) ==> recieve undefined
            const { teamName } = request.body;
           
            const newTeam = await this.teamRepo.create(teamName);
            console.log(newTeam);

            return response.json(newTeam)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return response.status(404).json(error);
        }
    }
};
```

```
const teamRepo: TeamRepository = new TeamRepository(new TypeOrmTeamRepo()); //here

class TeamController {
    public async addTeam(request: Request, response: Response) {
        try {
            const teamRepo: TeamRepository = new TeamRepository(new TypeOrmTeamRepo()); //or here
            const { teamName } = request.body;

            const newTeam = await teamRepo.create(teamName););
            console.log(newTeam);

            return response.json(newTeam)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return response.status(404).json(error);
        }
    }
};
```

Here are the repositories code:

```
class TeamRepository implements IBaseTeamRepo {
    private repository: IBaseTeamRepo;

    constructor(repository: IBaseTeamRepo) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public async create(team: BaseTeamModel): Promise<any> {
        return await this.repository.create(team);
    }
}
```

```
export default class TypeOrmTeamRepo implements IBaseTeamRepo {
    public async create(newTeamName: string): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const teamRepo = await getRepository(Team);
            console.log(newTeamName);

            const newTeam = await teamRepo.create({
                teamName: newTeamName
            });

            await teamRepo.save(newTeam);
    
            return newTeam;
        } catch(error) {
            return error;
        }
    }
};
```

and interfaces:

```
interface BaseTeamModel {
    teamName: string;
};

interface IBaseTeamRepo {
    create(BaseTeamModel): Promise<any>;
};

export {
    BaseTeamModel,
    IBaseTeamRepo,
}
```

and here are the routes.ts:

```
const teamController = new TeamController();

const adminRoutes = express.Router();

adminRoutes.post("/", teamController.addTeam);
```

Comment: Just guessing: `this` may not refer to your class instance depending on how you call your addTeam() method. I'd set a breakpoint in your addTeam() method instead of your console.log and check what's inside `this`.

Comment: Thank u Cristoph, just did that and seems you are correct, my this is undefined, but that is true only inside the addTeam method, because in my constructor i recieve the correct this, do you know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: It typically depends on how you call your `addTeam()` method and this code is not included in your post. Common example is when you pass your method as a higher order function. Common solution: Use an arrow function to wrap your call.

Comment: It worked just finem thank you very much, for the help,I was 2 days locked in this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was about the way I was calling addTeam, it was in the wrong scope, so didnt recognized the this.teamRepo the right wya, thanks Chistoph for the help:

It just need to change the routes.ts to:

```
const teamController = new TeamController();

const adminRoutes = Router();

adminRoutes.post("/", (request: Request, response: Response) => {
        return teamController.addTeam(request, response);
});
```